# MVC3 Passing Image to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating image in javascript and assigning that to a img element in javascript. How to pass that image to controller on ActionButton click in MVC3?

Javascript

```
var picture = jqplotToImg($('#ChartContent')); //method to change chart as picture, no needed here
var img = document.getElementById("img1");
img.src = picture;
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <img id="img1" name="img1" />
 @Html.ActionButton("Export","ExportData","Report")
}
```

Controller

```
public void ExportReport(FormCollection fc)
{
}
```

Comment: Do you want to post image as file to controller or what? img tag is not input tag, so it is not posted through Form post

Comment: yes i want to post image as file. The exact need is that i want to add image to excel. But the image is created here from client side. So thought of posting the image to the server first and then adding it to excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prompted the base64 string and then copied and used that to test and so it fails. I used ajax method for this and it works

```
    function ExportData() {
    var picture = jqplotToImg($('#ChartContent'));
    //prompt("", picture);

    $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
        url: '../Report/Base64ToImage',
        async: false,
        data: { source: picture },
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data);
        }
    });
    window.location.href = "../Report/ExportChart";
}

[HttpPost]
    public void Base64ToImage(string source)
    {
        string base64 = source.Substring(source.IndexOf(',') + 1);
        base64 = base64.Trim('\0');
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadFolder"].ToString();

        var file = Server.MapPath(path + "Chart.jpg");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`HTML5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) which allows you to upload the image asynchronously to the server.

And here's another [`example`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9273250/29407) of how to convert the image to Base64 string which could then be sent to the server using any means such as AJAX for example.

Comment: When i try to pass this to ImageUrl in asp.net, the image is not displayed

Comment: When i try to pass the below url to ImageUrl in asp.net, the image is not displayed     `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABG4AAAH0CAYAAABsCGvoAAAgAElEcABCEAAAhAIKAHETUAnhrAgAAEIQAACEIAABCAAAQhAAAIQgADihjUAAQhAAAIQgAAEIAABCEAAAhCAAAQCSgBxE9CJISwIQAACEIAABCAAAQhAAAIQgAAEIIC4YQ1AAAIQgAAEIAABCEAAAhCAAAQgAIGAEkDcBHRiCAsCEIAABCAAAQhAAAIQgAAEIAABCCBuWAMQgAAEIAABCEAAAhCAAAQgAAEIQCCgBBA3AZ0YwoIABCAAAQhAAAIQgAAEIAABCEAAAogb1gAEIAABCEAAAhCAAAQgAAEIQAACEAgoAcRNQCeGsCAAAQhAAAIQgAAEIAABCEAAAhCAAOKGNQABCEAAAhCAAAQgAAEIQAACEIAABAJKAHET0IkhLAhAAAIQgAAEI=`

Comment: Does your browser support the [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)? How does the `src` attribute of the image look like in the generated markup?