# how to convert image or file Upload to byte with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

how to convert image or file Upload to byte with java script ?
and send to web API with ajax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert image to byte array using javascript only to store image on sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258932/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-using-javascript-only-to-store-image-on-sql-s)

Comment: Not a dup since that will convert to string not bytes (ArrayBuffer). OP: please include the code you have tried with so far.