# upload file from Angular 5/6 to WebApi c#

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, file-upload

I need to convert a file to a byte array into my WebApi

my HTML template:

```
 <input style="display: none"  type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput>
 <button (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>
 <button (click)="onUpload()">Upload!</button>
```

end my component:

```
    onFileChanged(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]      
    }  
    onUpload() {   
      const uploadFile = new FormData();   
      uploadFile.append('string', this.selectedFile, 
                                   this.selectedFile.name);       
      this.http.post(URL ,uploadFile);        
    }
```

for this example not use service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to create a `FormData` object to upload the images

```
onUpload() {   

    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadFile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });   

    this.http.post('http://localhost:516./....', formData, options)
     .subscribe(event =>  console.log(event));        
}
```

Comment: I need to convert a file into a byte array my backand accept only byte array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258932/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-using-javascript-only-to-store-image-on-sql-s?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: i need to convert ANY file