# Convert an image to byte array using javascript

Tags: javascript, base64

The idea of the task is to create an incident in the ticketing platform and attach a screenshot to the ticket created using a chatbot. For the attachment to be done for the ticket created, I am using an upload attachment API which accepts the image in byte array type only.

API Body:

```
{
"_ProxyDetails": {
   "Password":"test@123",
   "ProxyID":0,
   "ReturnType":"JSON",
   "UserName":"user@itsm.com",
   "OrgID":1,
   "TokenID":""
},
"eModule":"IM",
"TicketID":14487, 
"FileByte":"", 
"AttachmentFileName":"testtextfile.txt"
}
```

Where `FileByte` needs to be a byte array. I need the image to be converted to a byte array using the built-in `JavaScript` library only. Can anyone help me to convert this image to `byte array` type?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258932/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-using-javascript-only-to-store-image-on-sql-s

Comment: Hey adrian , i have seen the question which naga pointed in the above comment. In that question they are converting it to base 64 string and sending the same String to C# code for byte array conversion. I dont need that kind of conversion. I would require a pure JS conversion only as i am doing this on a platform which supports JS only . So can you help me to convert the same using JS alone.

Comment: JSON doesn't understand bytearray. The field, as presented in your API Body example, is a unicode string.

Comment: @Ouroborus . Can you assist me to figure out how this byte array can be sent using API

Comment: Once you've converted the image to a data url as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258932/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-using-javascript-only-to-store-image-on-sql-s , you can take that, trim off the beginning portion, and convert the rest of it to a binary string. E.g. `atob(getBase64Image().split(',')[1])`

Comment: @Arulvelu did you get the answer?