# Javascript: how to get image as bytes from a page (without redownloading)

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

Given an existing browser page with images is there a way to get the bytes from an `<img>` element using Javascript?

I am not seeing any methods in [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) which would allow getting a byte array from the image element.

I have tried the following approach but this returns an empty byte array.

```js
var img = document.querySelector('.my_image');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.height = img.height;
canvas.width = img.width;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
body.appendChild(canvas);
var imageBytes = context.getImageData(img.width, img.height, 1, 1).data;
console.log(imageBytes);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following js code will fetch an image from an existing `<img..>` element as base64 *without re-downloading* the image (*assuming there is an image with the given selector on the page and that there is no [canvas cors violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674835/canvas-tainted-by-cross-origin-data), which will be the case when you click the Run button below*):

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.querySelector('img');
canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
var base64String = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(base64String);
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/40/40">
```

> NOTE: Running this code directly from the snippet will fail with an error message indicating a [cross-domain violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported). If you copy it to your own server then you'll get the base64-encoded content (❗️must **not** be a `file:///` URL). If you can't avoid the cross-domain issue then then you'll need to use [@DPardal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62511959/191246). It also works on a third-party domain if, for example, you inject the script with something like selenium.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a way to get the bytes from an `<img>` element using Javascript?

Not really, but you can use `fetch()`:

```js
(async () {
  const arrayBuffer = await (await fetch("img-url")).arrayBuffer();
})();
```

This shouldn't re-download the image because it's still cached.

Comment: Thanks, got this working with es5 js: `fetch(img.src).then(response => response.arrayBuffer()).then(buf => {console.log(buf);});`

Comment: This may not be possible if origin has CORS protection

Comment: And see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710001/how-to-convert-uint8-array-to-base64-encoded-string to convert arrayBuffer into a base64 encoded string

Answer (score 0):

I've found another contribution on StackOverflow with the same intention.

[How to convert image to byte array using javascript only to store image on sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258932/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-using-javascript-only-to-store-image-on-sql-s)

This is the relevant code:

```
var url;
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var img1=document.createElement("img"); 

function getBase64Image(){     
    url = document.getElementById("fileUpload").value;
    img1.setAttribute('src', url); 
    canvas.width = img1.width; 
    canvas.height = img1.height; 
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0); 
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    alert("from getbase64 function"+dataURL );    
    return dataURL;
}
```

Comment: This solution is re-downloading the image. It would make the code more readable if you renamed `p` to `url`.